# URL's Links breaking line on emails

Tags: email, url, hyperlink, footer

Im creating an newsletter email. It has a footer and the footer has some text altogether with some links to some of products. It works well in most inboxes, however on android 4.0, the links dont't allow more text to be next to them. They create a break-line.

See [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWE7Q.png)
Can you please help me out what's wrong with the code?

```
<table id="templateFooter" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-  text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #333; border-collapse: collapse !important; border-top-color: #FFFFFF; border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: 1px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td pardot-region="footer_content02" class="footerContent" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #dbdbdb; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 11px; line-height: 15px; text-align: left; padding: 20px;color:#aaa" align="left" valign="top"><span style="color:#fff;"><strong>ReviewPro</strong></span> is the leading provider of Guest Intelligence solutions to independent hotel brands worldwide. The company’s suite of cloud-based solutions includes <a style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" href="https://www.reviewpro.com/products/reputation-management-for-hotels/">Online Reputation Management (ORM)</a> and the <a style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" href="https://www.reviewpro.com/products/guest-survey-solution/">Guest Survey Solution (GSS)</a>, which enable clients to obtain a deeper understanding of reputation performance as well as operational/service strengths and weaknesses. We provide actionable insight to increase guest satisfaction, rankings on review sites/OTAs and ultimately revenue.<br>
          The company offers the industry-standard     <a style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" href="https://www.reviewpro.com/products/global-review-index/">Global Review Index™ (GRI)</a>, an online reputation score, which is used by thousands of hotels worldwide as a benchmark for reputation management efforts, based on review data collected from 161 OTAs and review sites in more than 45 languages. More than 19,000 hotel brands worldwide are currently using ReviewPro’s solutions. For more information about ReviewPro, please visit <a style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" href="https://www.reviewpro.com">www.reviewpro.com</a>.</td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the [code](http://codepen.io/mamotreto/pen/ZQqbxm)